# Is the functional sequence Uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following sequence pointwise convergent, if it is pointwisely convergent, then is it uniformly so?

$(ne^{-(n-x)^2})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ $(x\in\mathbb{R})$

I believe that the functional sequence is pointwise convergent to $0$, but I am unsure of how to assess whether it is uniformly so, if anyone can provide a hint as how to go about this, that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 4):

It can't be uniformly convergent to $0$. To see that, evaluate $f_n(n)$.

Comment: This answer was great, it gave me confidence in my thoughts. Thank you!